# Is the definite article missing in this sentence?

Tags: articles, definite-article

This is a sentence from a book:

> We do not intend here to describe the medieval sense of geographical space in its totality, but briefly to point out **some of differences** between it and our modern one.

Shouldn't there be the definite article before *differences*? I thought the sentence reads odd and ungrammatical, and should be rewritten as

> We do not intend here to describe the medieval sense of geographical space in its totality, but briefly to point out **some of the differences** between it and our modern one.

or

> We do not intend here to describe the medieval sense of geographical space in its totality, but briefly to point out **some differences** between it and our modern one.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your cited text hasn't been proofread (either include ***the***, or discard ***of***).

Comment: You are correct that the **some of** construction used here requires **the differences between**. As you yourself noted, you can avoid the need for a definite article by writing **some differences between.** And as Lambie said, you could grammatically write **differences between** although that formulation does not quite convey the same meaning as the other two, which imply that other differences exist, whereas Lambie's formulation neither affirms nor denies that implication.

Comment: Both of your alternatives are correct; the original isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are exactly right. Neither of your alternatives are clearly better than the other, though I slightly prefer the wordier one.